# How to extract lines from source file with reference file, add to the result file?

Tags: shell-script, solaris

I have a question and cannot figure out. 
It is Solaris.
the over simplified source & reference files.

s.txt source file:

```
dn: cn=task,cn=Groups,dc=domain 
changetype: modify 
add: uniquemember 
uniquemember: cn=user1,cn=users,dc=domain

dn: cn=task,cn=Groups,dc=domain 
changetype: modify 
add: uniquemember 
uniquemember: cn=user9,cn=users,dc=domain

dn: cn=task,cn=Groups,dc=domain 
changetype: modify 
add: uniquemember 
uniquemember: cn=user10,cn=users,dc=domain
```

r.txt reference file:

```
uniquemember: cn=user9,cn=users,dc=domain 
uniquemember: cn=user8,cn=users,dc=domain
```

I'd want a script for using the reference record uniquemember file to extract the source file's cn=user9's line and 3 lines Above, 
add to a result file usermember_

add.ldif:

```
dn: cn=task,cn=Groups,dc=domain 
changetype: modify 
add: uniquemember 
uniquemember: cn=user9,cn=users,dc=domain
```

Comment: Note that the proposed duplicate depends on non-standard GNU extensions to [the POSIX `grep` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) and isn't applicable to non-GNU systems like Solaris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use the values in `r.txt` as *keys* to extract matching multi-line records from `s.txt`, then try

```
awk 'NR==FNR {u[$2]++; next} $NF in u' r.txt RS= s.txt
```

- process `r.txt` with the default (newline) record separator, constructing associative array `u` with keys from the second whitespace-separated field; then
- unset the record separator `RS=` to switch to *paragraph mode* for the second file
- process `s.txt` in paragraph mode i.e. treating each blank-line-separated block as a single record, whose last field value `$NF` may then be used as a lookup value in `u`
- if `$NF` exists in `u`, print the whole record

---

To add space between the matched records:

If you have GNU awk (`gawk`) you can use the special variable `RT` to add back the original paragraph separators:

```
gawk 'NR==FNR {u[$2]++; next} $NF in u {print $0 RT}' r.txt RS= s.txt
```

More generally, you can append a single additional newline after every matched record:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {u[$2]++; next} $NF in u {print $0 "\n"}' r.txt RS= s.txt
```

or add an extra newline to the default *output* field separator:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {u[$2]++; next} $NF in u' r.txt RS= ORS='\n\n' s.txt
```

Comment: awk 'NR==FNR {u[$2]++; next} $NF in u' r.txt RS= s.txt
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1 , it is Solaris, How can it be modified for Solaris? thanks.

Comment: @SeanB in solaris try using `nawk` (either  /usr/bin/nawk or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk)

Comment: @steeldriver for new to scripting , it looks like magic. 2 questions: 1) what is space in RS= s.txt for? without it , it does not work. 2) how to modify it with such that there would be space in the result for multiple matches?

Comment: @SeanB please see updated answer

Comment: @steeldriver thanks a lot detailed explanations! one question, how to make gawk 'NR==FNR {u[$2]++; next} $NF in u {print $0 RT}' r.txt RS= s.txt for just one space, instead of two. the others are good with one space

Comment: @SeanB if you use gawk's `RT` then you will get however many blank lines follow the particular record in `s.txt` whether that's one, several - or none (in the case of a record at the end of the file, with no trailing separator)

Answer (score 0):

I understood from your question is that you would like to use a code to read key word `user` in `r.txt`, then search for this keyword in `s.txt`. Finally, print the line relevant to this keyword (and the previous three lines) `in s.txt` . You can write these lines in a file called `"code"`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if  [[ `egrep user9 r.txt` ]] ; then 
grep -B 3 user9 s.txt
fi
```

Give this file `"code"` permissions, then run it in terminal as follows:

```
code > add.ldif
```

The output is:

```
dn: cn=task,cn=Groups,dc=domain 
changetype: modify 
add: uniquemember 
uniquemember: cn=user9,cn=users,dc=domain
```

Let's say you have two entries for `user9` in `s.txt` as follows:

```
dn: cn=task,cn=Groups,dc=domain 
changetype: modify 
add: uniquemember 
uniquemember: cn=user1,cn=users,dc=domain

dn: cn=task,cn=Groups,dc=domain 
changetype: modify 
add: uniquemember 
uniquemember: cn=user9,cn=users,dc=domain

dn: cn=task,cn=Groups,dc=domain 
changetype: modify 
add: uniquemember 
uniquemember: cn=user18,cn=users,dc=domain

dn: cn=XXX,cn=XXX,dc=XXX 
changetype: XXX 
add: XXX 
uniquemember: cn=user9,cn=users,dc=domain
```

The previous code would find two entries for user9:

```
dn: cn=task,cn=Groups,dc=domain 
changetype: modify 
add: uniquemember 
uniquemember: cn=user9,cn=users,dc=domain
--
dn: cn=XXX,cn=XXX,dc=XXX 
changetype: XXX 
add: XXX 
uniquemember: cn=user9,cn=users,dc=domain
```

Comment: grep: illegal option -- B
it is Solaris. what is the option B in solaris? thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you want. I belive in solaris you could try to replace 'grep or egrep' by 'sed'. Something like 'sed -n '1,/user/p' s.txt | tail -3' this will find the line that contain the word "user" and the previous /3/ lines. Adjust as you want.